# null object reference error with pushView()

Tags: apache-flex, view, flex-spark

It's said that I can pass any kind of data when push a view to screen with `navigator.pushView()`method. I just simply pass an array like:

```
var arr:Array=[4,5,6,7,8,9];
navigator.pushView(SecondView,arr);
```

and in my SecondView constructor,no matter how I try to access it's data property,I get an ERROR :

> Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Am I doing it the wrong way ?

Comment: Are you eventually doing something with the data in SecondViews "data" property? As taken from the Api doc: "data specifies any data passed to the view. This object is written to the View.data property of the new view." (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html) So if you do something in the setter of the data property in SecondView, this might be causing the trouble.

Comment: well,I did nothing to the data of the SecondView except in the pushView() method. I have a commonView(extends View) class which specifies it's own width and height property etc,and sure did nothing about changing it's data. And my SecondView extends commonView,if it will be the cause of null data ? if so, how should I do to access the data exactly passed to the SecondView in pushView() method? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor must be called to create an instance of an object.  This must be done before any properties are given values i side that object.

As such, I would always expect the data property to be null in the constructor.

Read up on the [Flex Component LifeCycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html).  Step 1 and 2 are the important points for this problem:

> 1. You call the component’s constructor...
> 2. You configure the component by setting its properties...

You'll have to access the data property at some point not in the constructor.  Perhaps in an event listener, such as initialize or creationComplete.   Perhaps as part of a lifecycle method, such as updateDisplayList() or commitProperties().

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me twice! hah I once thought this might be the problem of constructor,and added an EventListener of Event.ADDED to my View,but this event dispatches many times during the pushView() method. Maybe i should try some other event type to do this. And I wanna as you another thing: I called the PopupManager.addPopUp() to display an alert window in one of my view,the codes are executed,but the window never showed up.But when I put those code into the root application(ViewNavigatorApplication), and call it from my view,it works.If I can use Popup windows only in this way?

Comment: @Hubcin Without reviewing your code; it is tough to guess what the problem may be.  You should be able to create a popup from any component.  Perhaps you should post a more detailed question on this issue.